# How to show the output in the respective file type in php

Tags: php, html, image, file-upload

I don't know I am doing it the correct way or not. Please help me with best way

I have to display the 7 file type on page load and reset will be display dynamic after clicking on the add more button.

I don't have any issue with displaying and insert the data into the database. I am using the below code to display the file type on the page.

I used label name in the array and depending upon the count of the label, my file type will be displayed.

```
<?php
      $labelname = array('label 1','label 2','label 3','label 4','label 5','label 6','label 7');
      $labelCount=count($labelname);
        ?>
   <div class="row mt-3">
      <?php 
      for ($i=0; $i < $labelCount; $i++) { 
       ?>
       <div class="col-lg-4 mb-4 ">
         <div class="documentUploadWrap">
            <label><?php echo $labelname[$i];?></label>
         <div class="upload_doc">
          <div class="closefile"> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="close_img"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a></div>
          <input type="file" name="societyDocUpload[]"  class="fileupload">
          <input type="hidden" name="societyDocUploadLabel[]" value="<?php echo $labelname[$i];?>">
          <input type="hidden" name="societyDocUpload[]" value="<?php echo $info['uploadedDoc'][$i]['upload_name'];?>">

          <div class="uploadInfo">
             <div class="upload_icon"></div>
             <p>Drop your image here, or <span>browse</span></p> 
             <span>Supports: JPEG, PNG, PPT, PPTX, PDF <br />Max Size: 5MB</span>
          </div>
          <div class="previewFile">
            <div class="previewFileIcon text-center"></div>
            <p class="fileNamePreview"><?php echo $info['uploadedDoc'][$i]['upload_name'] ?? '';?></p>
            <span class="fileSizePreview"><?php echo format_size(filesize($rootPath."/societyprofile/".$info['uploadedDoc'][$i]['upload_name']));?></span>
         </div>
       </div>
         </div>
      </div> 
    <?php } ?>
```

The user can use any of the file types and upload their respective file.
For example. I uploaded in the Label 4 and Label 7 file types. So I am getting the below an array and inserting the new row in the table.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [upload_label] => label 4
            [upload_name] => 100x100.png
            [society_id] => 11
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [upload_label] => label 7
            [upload_name] => 150x150.png
            [s_id] => 11
        )

)
```

I don't have any issue till inserting. Now I have to fetch the records and I am getting the below output.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [u_id] => 8
            [upload_label] => label 4
            [upload_name] => 100x100.png
            [society_id] => 11
            [is_active] => 1
            [date_of_added] => 2021-06-11 21:58:08
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [u_id] => 9
            [upload_label] => label 7
            [upload_name] => 150x150.png
            [society_id] => 11
            [is_active] => 1
            [date_of_added] => 2021-06-11 21:58:08
        )

)
```

The user uploaded the data in label 4 and label 7, so now I have to show the file name(upload_name) in label 4 and label 7, and the rest label will be empty.

For example below are the 7 file type.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Label 1 | Label 2 | Label 3 | Label 4 | Label 5 | Label 6 | Label 7
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

after fetching the data I have to show the below output. This is my expected output
**Note**:- label 4 and label 7 are filled.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Label 1 | Label 2 | Label 3 | 100x100.png | Label 5 | Label 6 | 150x150.png
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am getting the output

```
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    100x100.png | 150x150.png | Label 3 | Label 4 | Label 5 | Label 6 | Label 7
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I hope you will understand my issue. Would you help me out with this issue?

Comment: Ok you've said what you want, and what the expected output is. But you've forgotten to explain what the problem is...have you written some code to try and do this? If so, what goes wrong? Or are you stuck on some aspect of how to write it? Please clarify the issue.

Comment: @ADyson, My problem is, I uploaded the file on label 4 and label 7 but when I fetch the output then I am getting on label 1 and label2. I added my output in the question

Comment: Ok and where is the code which you use to show the output? As far as I can see you you've only shown us the upload form

Comment: @ADyson, I am getting in all the rows in this  print_r($info['uploadedDoc']); and array output i already added in the question. Do you want my SQL query?

Comment: No, where is the code where actually attempt to output it according to your expected output. Print_r is just debugging output. You need some code which reads the label data from that array and attempts to construct the correct output based on that.

Comment: @ADyson, I direclty added             <p class="fileNamePreview"><?php echo $info['uploadedDoc'][$i]['upload_name'] ?? '';?></p> and $info['uploadedDoc'] i am getting my all the files

Comment: That will just output them in the current order, I assume. To get the `Label 1 | Label 2 | Label 3 | 100x100.png | Label 5 | Label 6 | 150x150.png` you say you want, you will need some extra logic. Have you tried to write that?

Comment: @ADyson, I need an idea to get that output. I am confused that how to show on the respective field if foreach already runing.

Comment: 1. Make sure you output the data from the database in the label order. 2. On each loop, read the current label value from the array. Work out the difference between that and the label you last printed (or 0, the first time), and then print `Label 1 | Label 2 |` etc until you get to the current ID. Then, print the value from the array. On the next loop, repeat the process. This means you can fill in the gaps between each item in the array, by some simple counting.

Comment: OK. Let me implement this with my code.